# Get query string in context class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, asp.net-web-api2

How can I get query string info inside this class?

```
public partial class uData : DbContext
{
    public uData() : base("name=uData")       
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: why you would want to do that?

Comment: Need to change the connection-string based id in querystring (different clients - same schema).
Using restier to serve oData - but need to verify ids and switch to right DB.